# Google app engine & CDN

Tags: google-app-engine, cdn

When using Google app engine is there any benefit to use a CDN if i wanted my file resources as closer to users?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/133157/using-googles-app-engine-as-cdn-for-static-files

The thread says that GAE is not a CDN

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/133157/using-googles-app-engine-as-cdn-for-static-files

The thread says that GAE is not a CDN

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Certainly. Although App Engine may cache your static content close to users, it doesn't guarantee it will do so, and it won't cache your dynamic content for you. Using a CDN is as viable an option with App Engine as it is with any other platform.

Comment: Can you give a example how to cache your dynamic data using cdn?

Comment: Thanks Nick. And nice app engine blog!

Comment: @Illian That depends entirely on the CDN. Check the docs for whichever one you're pondering using - App Engine is no different to any other platform in this regard.

Answer (score 30):

Well, it is all about your budget, geography and profiling. Google app engine is free, and if properly configured it serves your content very nicely to various locations around the world. Many people actually use the app engine as a CDN! (see [here](http://www.digitalistic.com/2008/06/09/10-easy-steps-to-use-google-app-engine-as-your-own-cdn/), [here](http://24ways.org/2008/using-google-app-engine-as-your-own-cdn) and [here](http://coderjournal.com/2008/06/turn-google-app-engine-into-a-content-delivery-network-cdn/))

[Here is a blog post](http://blog.sallarp.com/google-app-engine-cdn/) comparing the performance of the app-engine, a commercial CDN and no CDN at all for hosting a static 1MB zipped file

Try [this free service](http://www.testyourhost.com/) (from a CDN...) to see how your app engine application performs.
[Here](http://www.watchmouse.com/en/) is another test site I've used

So, depending on where your site is geographically located, where your users are located and what your needs are, you need to profile the performance of the app engine and see if it is good enough. Will you get better performance from a commercial CDN? Most likely. But do you need it?

Comment: Awesome, wish I could favourite this answer :)

Comment: The blog post comparing performance went offline, but you can use archive.org to see what the results were: http://web.archive.org/web/20110311062309/http://blog.sallarp.com/google-app-engine-cdn/ (Essentially: DedicatedServer, GAE, CDN, ranked in order of better performance)

Comment: One of your reference links is not working any more: http://blog.sallarp.com/google-app-engine-cdn/

Answer (score 5):

You can try a tool like [just ping](http://just-ping.com/) to see the latency between many locations and the Google App Engine (which is also on different geographical locations). Might turn out a CDN is not needed for your audience.