# Final GAE vs AWS architectural decision

Tags: google-app-engine, scalability, amazon-web-services

I know this has been asked one way or another before, but most of the main issues to do with GAE stability seem to have been asked around the end of 2008, early 2009, or aren't directly related to games at scale (which I'm interested in).

Basically, I have been arguing back and forth with my business partner about whether to use GAE or AWS for the back-end of our social game engine, and now it's crunch time.  I love GAE (Java) for so many reasons, and although it used to be unstable, it's pretty good now.  The main argument in favour of AWS is the fact that AWS has proven itself with multiple games running tens of millions of active users per day.  The obvious pin-up child for AWS is Zynga, with its Farmville peaking at 80+million DAU.  And that's just one of the hugely successful games running on the AWS infrastructure.  Remarkable achievement.

So, one way or another it's KNOWN to work.  GAE on the other hand doesn't have any examples that I could find doing these sorts of numbers.  Not even close.  **So can I trust it?  Is there a single example of a large social game with 2 million+ Daily Active Users, using GAE?**

The main considerations for our social game back-end are:

1. Reliable CDN (Amazon CloudFront/S3 is excellent for this, as is Google's obviously excellent DataStore).
2. Ability to scale without falling over (AWS-EC2 is proven here, GAE doesn't seem to have examples of large game apps which can run into the 1000s of requests per second.  GAE used to be quite unstable in this regard and so is my main concern).
3. Reliable no-SQL database. (AWS-SimpleDB and Google's DataStore are both excellent for this.  We really don't need SQL).
4. Support/someone to call/contact if there is a problem.  (This is one of the biggest worries with GAE.  I have no idea who I can call, or if it's even possible.  AWS has an SLA and support.)

I look forward to your thoughts, but please also note, this is not intended to start any sort of flame war.  I love both systems, but both have their positives and negatives, but I'm about to make an architectural decision that likely won't be undone moving forward.

Regards,

Shane

Comment: GAE do now have special plans for businesses which do mention SLAs and support: http://code.google.com/appengine/business/

Comment: @tomlog: App engine for business appears to be for enterprise intranet apps (eg charged at $8 per user). It would be nice if it was possible to purchase similar SLAs on the regular app engine.

Comment: @Saxon: you're absolutely right. I did miss that pricing bit.

Comment: I just noticed in the FAQ that they plan to release pricing for public apps too, so that could be an option: http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/business.html#existingapp

Comment: @Saxon Yes, depending on Google's cost plan, the public apps looks like it could be the go longer term.

Comment: As of 2015 GAE is unstable so I hope you chose AWS.

Answer (score 8):

I've never worked with AWS-EC2 so I'm going to share my knowledge just on the Google App Engine side.

1. Google App Engine is not meant to be a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network); though it can serve static content through its powerful infrastructure providing caching close to the users, it does not guarantee the same kind of high quality and high availability service of a real CDN because it's not part of its duties.
   Further data:

   - Maximum size of a file using the BlobStore service: 2 Gigabytes
   - Maximum size of a static file: 10 Megabytes
   - Currently App Engine  [always returns 200 status](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=575) for static  files even on Conditional gets (you have to rely on third party caching library like [cirruxcache](http://code.google.com/p/cirruxcache/) for example).
2. Recently Google App Engine team has shut down the [App Gallery](http://appgallery.appspot.com/) for one simple reason: too many Toy Apps!
   Google wants to counteract this tendency showing successful businesses case studies; here are some of them:

   - [BuddyPoke](http://www.buddypoke.com/) (viral Facebook app with 65 million installs)
   - [WalkScore](http://www.walkscore.com/) (serves 3 million request a day to thousands of real estate partner sites)
   - [Webfillings](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/08/webfilings-streamlines-sec-reporting.html)
   - [Snapabug](http://www.snapabug.com/)
   - [Optimizely](http://www.optimizely.com/)
   - [Ubisoft Facebook TikTok game](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/08/recent-happenings-ticktock-parallel.html)

   Other interesting case studies [here](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/casestudies.html)
3. "*We are well aware of downtimes and reliability issues, and are working hard to solve them: Improving App Engine reliability is our number one priority*" was recently said by a Google Developer Relations Manager [here](http://www.carlosble.com/?p=719).
   App Engine is still in beta and is an evolving platform so you have to be prepared to deal with downtimes and issues.
4. Google App Engine team has just launched a preview of [App Engine for Business](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/business/) providing 99.9% uptime service level agreement and premium developer support available.

*Here is my opinion for what it's worth*:
I'm aware that it's a tough call; having read a lot of [articles about GAE](http://www.reddit.com/r/appengine/) I have mixed feelings about it because you can go from the recent catastrophic [Carlos Ble](http://www.carlosble.com/?p=719) report to the happy experience of [Flower Garden](http://gamesfromwithin.com/google-app-engine-as-back-end-for-iphone-apps) or [Gri.pe](http://grack.com/blog/2010/11/23/why-were-really-happy-with-appengine-and-not-going-anywhere-else/).
App Engine for Business looks promising and I would consider it in the case of a serious business project plan.
The fresh [SDK 1.4.0](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/12/happy-holidays-from-app-engine-team-140.html) is huge and it clearly shows that the Team is really pushing hard to fix some annoying issues (Warmup requests) and relaxing some limitations (10 minutes process on TaskQueue).

Last thing to consider: if you are going to have big numbers, the Google App Engine Team will probably take your app as a successfull case study to follow with a boost of free and powerful Hype.

Comment: +1. I like GAE's other features enough that I'm willing to see how things develop on points 3 and 4.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, we now return 304s for static files with conditional gets.

Comment: @Nick some users say it's still not fixed [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=575)

Comment: Thanks for the Carlos Ble reference, I hand't seen that.  Very interesting.  I think you're right though, I can't trust the vanilla GAE, but the new GAE for Business looks very interesting (but only when they support regular apps, not intranet apps, which is apparently coming soon).  I've signed up for the beta, so I'll keep my on this closely.

Answer (score 5):

BuddyPoke is one example of a large-scale social app running on GAE. How large I'm not sure. This article says 30m daily page views (not users):

http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2008/10/app-engine-case-studies.html

Their facebook page says 2.7 million monthly (not daily) users:

http://www.facebook.com/buddypoke

Although, they are also on a heap of other social networks:

http://www.buddypoke.com/

Personally I decided to go with GAE, for a couple of main reasons:

- The unit of scalability is a single request, not a whole instance like it is with AWS.
- I can work at a higher level, without having to worry about configuring instances.

If your point 4 is a big one for you, then you may be better off with AWS. With GAE there appears to be nothing you can do, and no-one you can contact.

About a week ago I had an issue with my app - it had suddenly started failing in Google's code, in a location which had been working fine for the last 5 days, ie since I had last uploaded my app. The only way to report issues to Google seems to be via their production issue template, here:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue

I reported the issue, and didn't hear anything. Since it's running on Google's servers I was unable to resort to any 'usual' emergency tactics like restarting a server. An hour later and the problem resolved itself - I'm not sure if someone at Google saw my message and fixed something, or if it just went away. I updated my bug report to say the problem was fixed, but even now a week later the issue hasn't been closed or even acknowledged. Also since the issue has to be posted publicly, my app is now getting random hits from bots.

Admittedly my app is currently only in beta and so only has a hundred or so users, and so it wasn't a major incident for me. If I was getting thousands / millions of hits, maybe either Google would have noticed the problem themselves earlier, or they would have paid more attention to my bug report.

On your point 3, even my small app with a small amount of traffic throws occasional data store errors (even during times which aren't reported on the availability charts as outages).

Having said this, I still like GAE (I am using the Python version), and plan to stick with it. The promise of GAE is its scalability - although it falls over occasionally now for my small traffic, it shouldn't fall over any more when it scales to much more traffic (ie your point 2), provided I've coded it correctly to avoid contention. I'll see how it goes.

Finally regarding your point 1, the blobstore and/or static files are more like a CDN on GAE, than the datastore. However for very large amounts of traffic, a real CDN may be cheaper. It's also not necessarily a CDN, see [Google app engine & CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597214/google-app-engine-cdn).

Comment: @Saxon +1 I feel you when you say "throws occasional data store errors". I hate especially "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request" or "A serious problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit" or "The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable."

Comment: Thanks for your considered response.  BuddyPoke seems to be the only app mentioned at scale, and even then there are no stats on it's usage of GAE.  For example, it's impossible to discover any hard information on their requests per second, or reliability.  To be honest, BuddyPoke is a pretty resilient app by design, in that it's not firing many GET/POSTs per user, like a social game does.

Comment: I also meant to add that your support story is the scariest scenario for me; millions of people playing your game, then something goes down and you're stranded. In the social games space, that's a completely unacceptable disaster, and research shows how quickly people leave your app for good under these conditions.

Comment: @Shane: Agreed, it could have been a disaster if we were a bit further along. In contrast, a year ago we had a dedicated server at SoftLayer. Our game appeared on the front page of Digg and our server fell over. We submitted a 'help!' request to SoftLayer's support, and within moments they were in there killing dead processes and restarting things, for free. Other times they helped us with things for a small fee ($3). The experience of having a server fall over is one of the reasons I've moved to GAE for the automatic scaling. I hope that one day GAE's support will be as good as SoftLayer's :)

Comment: It's fair to say that BuddyPoke is not even respecting the App Engine TOS because it is using more than a app to handle different tasks as reported [here](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/1/22/how-buddypoke-scales-on-facebook-using-google-app-engine.html).

Comment: @systempuntoout Wow, I didn't realise they used multiple apps to separate out functionality.  Obviously it architecturally makes sense, but I dismissed it because of the TOS issue you mention.  How can they do this?

Comment: well, probably because BuddyPoke is one the biggest App