# Google apps server or Amazon server

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, mobile, amazon-ec2

why would I prefer Google Apps server over one of Amazon's various offerings?

the main purpose would be to store data for mobile apps, so I suppose cost and programming language are the biggest deciding factors.

Is there a good primer I can read? I'm mainly looking for resources to then come back here with more detailed questions

Comment: Kindly cease and desist from asking [Gorilla vs Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) questions on StackOverflow. It's fine and even encouraged to ask such questions anywhere else on t3h int4rw3bz.

Comment: @bernie I don't understand how this is a bad question.  I bet that this is a question that everyone who wants to outsource their infrastructure thinks of. I don't believe the OP was trying to start a flame war or anything, I think they just wanted to know what factors they should consider in making their own decision. I maybe assuming quite a bit, but I don't see how the Gorilla vs shark post applies to this when someone asks where they can learn the differences themselves.

Comment: @Lostsoul: it's decidedly *not* a bad question. Some may even say it's a great question. That does not change the fact that it is simply not a good fit for this site. I'm sorry I didn't make that more clear.

Comment: The article bernie linked to makes it pretty clear why these questions aren't a good fit. Also, I've never heard of "Google apps server". What is it?

Comment: @bernie I agree not a programming question. I was thinking maybe this would have been better to post at serverfault.

Comment: It would be just as non constructive at serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think google app engine is good but I found it rather limited. I could only push my python or java code to it.  I decided to go with AWS because I realized, in my specific case, I need other services running and different versions of certain software(some of my apps run python3 and some run python 2.6).

I also found the usage pricing of google a bit confusing.  For example, how do I know how many IO requests my system will have? With EC2 I didn't have to measure it, it gives you unlimited IO on your server and to S3.  I only pay for an hour.

With that said, there are good reasons to choose google over AWS.  If you are simply pushing code and do not depend on any third party services(all the services stem from your own app) then google maybe a good choice.

If someone can provide a good primer than great but I would strongly suggest you just get your feet wet and try both services out.  AWS offers a micro instance for free for a year ( http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/ ) and I believe google does as well( http://www.google.com/enterprise/cloud/appengine/pricing.html ).  Test both out and see which one you like.

Answer (score 1):

This thread seemed to generate some good discussion and is centered around games:

[Final GAE vs AWS architectural decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332377/final-gae-vs-aws-architectural-decision)

Another SO post with lengthy discussion:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64727/windows-azure-vs-amazon-ec2-vs-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

IBM DeveloperWorks has a nice comparison between major PaaS vendors [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-paasshootout/).

The main drawback of Google App Engine is the lack of flexibility: it only implements partially the Java EE standard and it forces you to use a Non-Relational data store for persistence (although, Google SQL is planning to get out soon). With this restrictions, your application is less portable.

On the other side, Amazon offers includes a Tomcat Container that it's a fully complaint Java Web Container. Amazon also lets you choose between a relational and a No-SQL repository so flexibility and portability is assured. But the prices are quite expensive, so it’s not recommended for small projects or hobbyist developers (like me)